# is there a difference of initializing the derived class's base constructor by () or {}?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I wanna know if I wanna inherent a constructor from the base class can I use
`()` instead of `{}` to embrace the constructor's parameters,

the is like this :

```
class base
{
    private:
        int a , b;
    public:
        base(int a , int b) : a{a} , b{b} {};
}

class derived
{
    private:
        int c , d ;

    public:
        derived(int a , int b , int c , int d) : base(a , b) , c{c} , d{d} {};
                                                   ^
                                                   |

                                          //i mean above base(a , b) istead of base{a ,b}
}
```

Comment: Of course it's "undeclared identifier". Can you point which line of `derived`'s class defines what these `a` and `b` are? Just because there are some parameters with the same name in the base class, that doesn't mean anything. It is the derived class that gets constructed first, and it needs to know what everything is. You need to figure out which parameters your derived class needs to pass down to the base class's constructor, and this is something that only you would know what it should be, since only you know how these classes should work. See your C++ book for more information.

Comment: It should look like `derived(int input) : base(a,b)` but you need to define what `a` and `b` are. You can't just make it up. Maybe you mean `derived(int intput, int a, int b) : base(a,b)`

Comment: What do you expect `derived(int input) : base(a, b)` to do? Let's look at a concrete case. Suppose someone defines a variable using `derived x{3};` -- what steps do you expect to be taken when constructing `x`? What values go where?

Answer (score 1):

In your `class derived`, you are trying to initialize the base class with the two values `a, b`. That's fine, base has that constructor. But where are you getting `a, b` from?

Unless it's a global variable we can't see, the compile will fail because `a` and `b` are undeclared; you have not created them anywhere while trying to initialize your base class.